# How can I route to an action with an input button in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an input  button and I want to redirect to a view or action when it's clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just specify the appropriate URL for the action of the form that the button is part of?

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect to a view. You could redirect to a controller action which in turn will render a view. You could do it using javascript:

```
<input type="button" id="foo" value="foo" />
```

and once the DOM is loaded attach a click event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("foo") %>';
    });
});
```

If you are talking about a submit button then you don't need javascript, simply set the `action` of the associated `form`:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName")) { %>
    <input type="submit" value="foo" />
<% } %>
```

But I think that in your situation the most semantically correct is to simply use an anchor tag which you could [style with CSS to look as a button](http://mezzoblue.com/articles/supplements/2008/08/anchor-buttons/).

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the input button needed to go to a different url that I can map with a link.